# how to send imges to skype with integration of flask-assistant and dialogflow

Tags: python, flask, dialogflow-es, skype

I am currently working on Skypebot with help of Dialogflow and flask-assistant.I am getting trouble in sending images to the skype through flask assistant.It will work fine through the dialogflow,but it will not work with flask assistant.
  In Dialogflow I create an intent as 'images' and user response as 'show'.But in the result it will not show the image,only display the text as 'pythonlogo'. 
I am using the resp.card() method as follow to send image:

```
@assist.action('images')
def show_card():
resp = ask("python")
resp.card(text="Python logo",
          title="logo",
          img_url='http://mherman.org/presentations/flask- 
                        kubernetes/images/flask-logo.png'
          )
return resp
```

The response on server side shows only upto text,but not of image

```
2019-03-13 17:50:40:flask_assistant:INFO: Request: {
   " Incoming Contexts": [],
   "Intent": "images",
   "Missing Params": [],
    "Received Params": {},
   "Source": "skype"
}
```

In the Skypebot,it will shown only text as "python logo",but not getting any image through image url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having Rich conversations like images,cards etc are probably limited to Google Assistant through Flask assistant.Wait till upgrade